# Spring Boot - Hibernate - Multitenancy @ManyToOne (mapping) issue for different schema entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am developing a schema-based multitenant Spring Boot application. I have a public schema for common tables such as "User" and many schemas for each tenant. I can handle many things such as request routing to different schemas.

However, I have want to map two fields, one of them is a field of public schema object, another is a field of a schema-based object's field. I could not find a solution for that. I can give two classes:

Public schema object is that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
public class User extends AbstractEntity<UUID> {

    @NotNull
    @Email(message = "Please provide acceptable mail address")
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 60)
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String surname;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role = Role.BASIC_USER;

    private boolean confirmed = false;
}
```

Tenant based schema object is that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_user")
public class CompanyUser extends AbstractEntity<UUID> {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role = Role.BASIC_USER;
}
```

When I run it I get this error:
`@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on x.CompanyUser.user references an unknown entity: y.User`

How can I configure them to run properly?

Comment: Looks like you imported a wrong `User` from another package, can you add the imports of these classes?

Comment: No, I am not. No debt because I can go to my User class by clicking over User.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, your `@EntityScan` configuration wrong and the `User` entity is not picked up by Spring and hence not visible as entity to Hibernate. Put a break point to the line where the exception is thrown and try to figure out why Hibernate thinks `User` is unknown.